# How merge route in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am beginner in Laravel. I have project in Laravel 6
I have this code in routes/admin.php:

```
Route::name('admin.')->group(function(){
    Auth::routes(['register' => false, 'reset' => false, 'confirm' => false, 'verify' => false]);

    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('admin.home');
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
});
Route::group(['prefix' => ''], function () {
    //Auth::routes(['register' => false, 'reset' => false, 'confirm' => false, 'verify' => false]);
    /* Pages */
    Route::get('/pages', 'PageController@index')->name('page.index');
    Route::get('/pages/create', 'Admin\PageController@create')->name('page.create');
    Route::post('/pages/store', 'Admin\PageController@store')->name('page.store');
    Route::get('/pages/edit' . '/{id?}', 'Admin\PageController@edit')->name('page.edit');
    Route::put('/pages/update', 'Admin\PageController@update')->name('page.update');
    Route::delete('/pages/destroy'. '/{id?}', 'Admin\PageController@destroy')->name('page.destroy');

    /* Users */
    Route::get('/users', 'Admin\UserController@index')->name('user.index');
    Route::get('/users/create', 'Admin\UserController@create')->name('user.create');
    Route::post('/users/store', 'Admin\UserController@store')->name('user.store');
    Route::get('/users/edit' . '/{id?}', 'Admin\UserController@edit')->name('user.edit');
    Route::put('/users/update', 'Admin\UserController@update')->name('user.update');
    Route::delete('/users/destroy'. '/{id?}', 'Admin\UserController@destroy')->name('user.destroy');
});
```

All from this URL need login user (admin).

In RouteServiceProvider I have:

```
protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('api')
            ->middleware('api')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    }

    protected function mapAdminRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix(config('app.admin_prefix'))
            ->middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace.'\Admin')
            ->group(base_path('routes/admin.php'));
    }

    protected function mapAdminOnlyRoutes()
    {
        Route::middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace. '\Admin')
            ->group(base_path('routes/admin.php'));
    }
```

How can I change my admin.php?
Now user which is no login can view my url

**CODE AFTER UPDATE:**
Code after update. Is this code written in an optimal way?

```
Route::name('admin.')->group(function(){
    Auth::routes(['register' => false, 'reset' => false, 'confirm' => false, 'verify' => false]);

    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('admin.home');
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
});


Route::group(['prefix' => ''], function () {
    /* Pages */
    Route::get('/pages', 'PageController@index')->middleware('auth')->name('page.index');
    Route::get('/pages/create', 'PageController@create')->middleware('auth')->name('page.create');
    Route::post('/pages/store', 'PageController@store')->middleware('auth')->name('page.store');
    Route::get('/pages/edit' . '/{id?}', 'PageController@edit')->middleware('auth')->name('page.edit');
    Route::put('/pages/update', 'PageController@update')->middleware('auth')->name('page.update');
    Route::delete('/pages/destroy'. '/{id?}', 'PageController@destroy')->middleware('auth')->name('page.destroy');

    /* Users */
    Route::get('/users', 'UserController@index')->middleware('auth')->name('user.index');
    Route::get('/users/create', 'UserController@create')->middleware('auth')->name('user.create');
    Route::post('/users/store', 'UserController@store')->middleware('auth')->name('user.store');
    Route::get('/users/edit' . '/{id?}', 'UserController@edit')->middleware('auth')->name('user.edit');
    Route::put('/users/update', 'UserController@update')->middleware('auth')->name('user.update');
    Route::delete('/users/destroy'. '/{id?}', 'UserController@destroy')->middleware('auth')->name('user.destroy');
});
```

Comment: If you want to secure your admin routes you can add `auth` middleware or `auth:admin` if you want to use an admin guard if you have one defined

Comment: I just want these routes to be visible after logging in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you want to protect `Route::get('/users', 'Admin\UserController@index')->name('user.index');` route so that only users may access it, you need to do like so:

`Route::get('/users', 'Admin\UserController@index')->middleware('auth')->name('user.index');`

But if you need to open it to only admin and not other users, you can create your own middleware. See docs https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware#defining-middleware.

Then you need to register your middleware in `$routeMiddleware` in `App\Http\Kernel.php`. For example, you register your middleware as `admin`. Then you would protect your route like so:

`Route::get('/users', 'Admin\UserController@index')->middleware('admin')->name('user.index');`

Comment: I'm update my firs post. Is this code written in an optimal way?

Comment: This is for a single route. For a group of routes, you can do like so: `Route::prefix('your-prefix')
    ->middleware('auth')
    ->group(function () {}` and then you would define the routes inside without `->middleware()` since it is now applied to the whole group.

Comment: When I change: Route::group(['prefix' => ''], function () { to: Route::prefix('admin') ->middleware('auth') ->group(function () { - I have 404 errors

Comment: Try this `Route::group(['prefix' => '', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function () {}`. Also what 404 errors. If you can post them here I can help better

Answer (score 0):

in the first step you can use the resource method to create create, store, show, edit, update and delete routes. like this:

```
Route::resource('shops', 'ShopController');
```

and for authenticated users for can use the auth middleware to your routes like these ways:

```
    Route::get('profile', ['middleware' => 'auth', function()
       {
          // Only authenticated users may enter...
       }]);

      // With A Controller...

      Route::get('profile', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@show']);

      Route::group(['prefix' => 'backend', 'as' => 'backend.', 'namespace' => 'Backend', 'middleware' => ['web', 'auth], function(){})
```